Как работать с байтами в java
Создал я виртуальную машину которая выполняет какие-то инструкции
Как мы знаем в основном байт код хранится в бинарном формате а не в текстовом, и я тоже так хочу сделать
То вопрос, как мне правильно читать и выполнять байт код
Если с текстом все просто, в случае простого синтаксиса хватит метода split() что бы разделить команду от аргументов...
Но в случае байтов там все сложнее, например я не знаю как отделить байт инструкцию от байтов полезной информации как например текст, числа, адрес памяти, не знаю как инструкции разделить, в текстовом формате можно разделить по "\n" или другой символ, но как в моем случае?
Ну и последнее, стоит ли создавать такой байт код? Может пойдут просто обычные асемблерные инструкции, или это будет влиять на скорость выполнения из-за операций с текстом (типа split, substring, регулярки...)

"как отделить байт инструкцию от байтов полезной информации как например текст, числа, адрес памяти" - хранить "большие" блоки данных отдельно, в отдельной части кода, из основной части обращаться по адресу. Отделить от данных это не самая интересная проблема, интересная - как отделить машинные инструкции одну от другой: тут два подхода - RISC (как на ARM процессорах, например) с фиксированной длиной инструкции и CISK (как в процессорах на intel архитектуре, например) - длина инструкции почти не ограничена, но какой-нибудь более процессор может какие-то более новые инструкции не поддерживать.

"Ну и последнее, стоит ли создавать такой байт код? Может пойдут просто обычные асемблерные инструкции, или это будет влиять на скорость выполнения из-за операций с текстом (типа split, substring, регулярки...)" - ну это так самые простые интерпретаторы работали, для какого-нибудь BASIC. Сейчас практически любые интерпретаторы сначала компилируют текст в байт-код, потом его исполняют.

@insolor "Сейчас практически любые интерпретаторы сначала компилируют текст в байт-код, потом его исполняют" -  это я знаю но мне интересует будет ли это влиять на скорость, или при работе с байтами вм будет работать быстрее, просто мне не особо важно как все сейчас работает, я только учусь это делать

Если вы вы предполагаете, что код будет запускаться один раз - то разницы практически не будет. Если вы будете код запускать несколько раз без модификации, то заново парсить исходный код не нужно будет, это значительно ускорит исполнение.

@insolor "хранить "большие" блоки данных отдельно, в отдельной части кода, из основной части обращаться по адресу" - это я так понял надо разбить код на несколько разделов типа .text, .data...? | "из основной части обращаться по адресу" - этот момент меня интересует, допустим создал файл .data, и как именно мне определить под каким адресом будет находится информация

Ну, примерно так. Можно не прямо явно на секции делить, а просто дописывать эти данные после кода, потом поправлять в коде адреса.

@insolor ну и меня интересует какие типы даных можно использовать для эмуляции озу, регистров, например для озу может пойти массив Object, а для регистров HashMap, но мне кажетстя что лучше что то другое использовать, вот проблема в том что в джаве статическая типизация, динамических переменных нету, из-за этого мне приходится использовать Object[], но это не удобно, может надо использовать байты для сохраниение информации вместо int, String...

Для памяти можно просто массив байт использовать. Для регистров - просто класс с ограниченным набором полей. Зачем вам вдруг Object понадобился - не понятно.

Object я использовал что бы была возможнось сохранять все типы данных, просто первый интерпретатор я на питоне писал, вот там динамическая типизация и не было таких проблем, "Для регистров - просто класс с ограниченным набором полей" - а что за поля нужно добавить, как мне реализировать класс регистра?

"Object я использовал что бы была возможнось сохранять все типы данных," - значит это не ассемблер, и не байткод.

ключевое слово "использовал", но понял что что-то не так вот и решил переделать
